# Which is better practice for adding a class using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$("#" + parentElementId + " label").attr("class", "disabled")
```

VS

```
$('#radiolabel').addClass('disabled');
```

Which are the pros and cons?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some advantages of the two ways to do this:

`addClass("disabled")` Pros:

1. If you have other classes on your object, `addClass()` will preserve those while adding a new class.  I pretty much always want to preserve the ability to use other classes for CSS styling reasons or common selector reasons so `addClass()` makes it possible to add the `disabled` class without disturbing other classes on the same object for other reasons.
2. The code reads a little more self-explanatory since the name `addClass()` tells someone reading the code exactly what it's doing.
3. `addClass()` automatically manages separators between class names so there is no extra accumulation of separators when you have multiple class names which can occur if you just get the current classname and add onto it yourself with string manipulation.

`attr("class") = "disabled"` Pros:

1. If you only ever want one class name on the object, this one statement insures that you will have only one class name.
2. A direct assignment of the one class can be faster than `addClass()` which has to examine what's there first and add a class to the pre-existing classes which jQuery does with a regex match.  Max speed would actually be with element.className = "disabled" (no jQuery at all).

Answer (score 13):

The two are not the same.  Using `attr` will replace the whole attribute.  `addClass` will add the class to the existing classes.

As the name suggests `addClass` is made for this specific purpose, so I'd use that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for `addClass`, it's easier to read, and if your editor supports code completion, also faster to type.

Comment: I don't know if being able to type something faster means its better practice :P

Answer (score 1):

You better go for the `addClass()` you will save time and writting, and gain more efficiency.